# Google Script for loop array becoming undefined after first run through

Tags: javascript, arrays, logging, google-sheets

First time writing on the forum after coming here often... So bear with me.

The code is attached to a Google sheet - operating out of google script V10.

The basic premise is to have the sheet able to be duplicated per event and allow us to create end of event reports for our clients - this process works, however requires a lot of tedious steps to make it work thus I am currently making this script to automate it based on the data coming in and then further simplify the process so it doesn't take hours, only minutes to produce.

I have a lengthy piece of code that is looping and operating without errors - except some of the values are becoming undefined after the first loop through. I've attached my execution log for reference.

Here's how it should run

1. User places two sets of raw data into the 2nd and 3rd tab
2. User runs script (from a menu item, which is working fine)
3. Script grabs unique values from "context" column in tab 3
4. Places step 3 values into array
5. Creates a new tab for each item in array

5-1: Paste 4 cells of information (1: text, 3: formulas)

5-2: Set tab name based on array value

5-3: Remove all formulas/code and paste values only - (I do this because on export the code breaks so just want the values to remain after the formulas have been entered) I haven't implemented this

6. Fill array values onto first tab

It's doing some of the above steps but because the array "current value" becomes undefined it's not filling the cells and sheet tab name correctly. Otherwise it's doing what I want it to do.

The google sheet it's attached to: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aZBNp6b47-qp-1m-1dX0XtnGG2o1Nrs4AbckGInt0t8/edit?usp=sharing

```
//Build session reports
function allSessionNames2() {

//All Available variables
var TemplateSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
Logger.log("TemplateSheet: " + TemplateSheet);
var TemplateTab = TemplateSheet[3].getName();
Logger.log("TemplateTab: " + TemplateTab);
var OverviewSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
var overviewTab = OverviewSheet[0].getName();
var CurrentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[2];
var CurrentSpread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var CurrentTab
var OnAIRSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
var OnAIRTab = OnAIRSheet[2]
var CurrentSessionName = "";
var LastRow = OnAIRTab.getLastRow();
var SessionNamesArray = OnAIRTab.getRange(2, 15, LastRow, 1).getValues();
var SessionNamesArraySize = SessionNamesArray.length;
var TemplateContentsA = "Session Name";
var TemplateContentsB = "Contact Identifier";
var Range1 = "B1";
var Range2 = "A1";
var Range3 = "A3";
var Range4 = "A4";
var Formula1 = "=iferror(FILTER(\'\RAW OnAIR\'\!B:V,REGEXMATCH(\'\RAW OnAIR\'\!O:O,B1)),\"\Session does not exist\"\)";
var Formula2 = '=FILTER(\'\RAW OnAIR\'\!1:1,\'\RAW OnAIR\'\!A1 = \"\Contact Identifier\"\)';



//1. Fill Formula on Overview page
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("A4").setFormula("=UNIQUE('RAW OnAIR'!P2:P)");
Logger.log("Fill Formula on Overview tab - cell A4")

//2. Retrieve all sessions into array
Logger.log("SessionNamesArray: " + SessionNamesArray);
Logger.log("SessionNamesArraySize: " + SessionNamesArraySize);

//3. Begin loop for creating a tab per session
for (var i = 0; i < SessionNamesArraySize - 1; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
  Logger.log("Starting Tab creation loop");
  Logger.log("Variable i: " + i);
} else {
  Logger.log("restarting tab creation loop");
  Logger.log("Variable i: " + i);
}
  var ActiveSessionName = SessionNamesArray[0][i];
  Logger.log("Current Session name: " + SessionNamesArray[0][i]);
  Logger.log("Current Session name: " + ActiveSessionName);
  //Create new sheet + paste code
  CurrentSpread.insertSheet(ActiveSessionName);
  //Paste code
  Logger.log("Setting active range B1 - set value...");
  CurrentSpread.setActiveSelection(Range1).setValue(ActiveSessionName);
  CurrentSpread.setActiveSelection(Range2).setValue("Session Name:");
  CurrentSpread.setActiveSelection(Range4).setFormula(Formula1);
  CurrentSpread.setActiveSelection(Range3).setFormula(Formula2);
  Logger.log("Setting values in cells.... Done.")
  
}

//4. Confirm tab count equals total session count minus the first 3 tabs
    return Logger.log("Loop completed for sessions: " + ActiveSessionName);
}
```

```
9:27:42 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:27:42 AM  Info    TemplateSheet: Sheet,Sheet,Sheet,Sheet
9:27:42 AM  Info    TemplateTab: Template
9:27:43 AM  Info    Fill Formula on Overview tab - cell A4
9:27:43 AM  Info    SessionNamesArray: Alphabet stuff,b,C,d,E,
9:27:43 AM  Info    SessionNamesArraySize: 6
9:27:43 AM  Info    Starting Tab creation loop
9:27:43 AM  Info    Variable i: 0
9:27:43 AM  Info    Current Session name: Alphabet stuff
9:27:43 AM  Info    Current Session name: Alphabet stuff
9:27:43 AM  Info    Setting active range B1 - set value...
9:27:43 AM  Info    Setting values in cells.... Done.
9:27:43 AM  Info    restarting tab creation loop
9:27:43 AM  Info    Variable i: 1
9:27:43 AM  Info    Current Session name: undefined
9:27:43 AM  Info    Current Session name: undefined
9:27:43 AM  Info    Setting active range B1 - set value...
9:27:43 AM  Info    Setting values in cells.... Done.
9:27:43 AM  Info    restarting tab creation loop
9:27:43 AM  Info    Variable i: 2
9:27:43 AM  Info    Current Session name: undefined
9:27:43 AM  Info    Current Session name: undefined
9:27:44 AM  Info    Setting active range B1 - set value...
9:27:44 AM  Info    Setting values in cells.... Done.
9:27:44 AM  Info    restarting tab creation loop
9:27:44 AM  Info    Variable i: 3
9:27:44 AM  Info    Current Session name: undefined
9:27:44 AM  Info    Current Session name: undefined
9:27:44 AM  Info    Setting active range B1 - set value...
9:27:45 AM  Info    Setting values in cells.... Done.
9:27:45 AM  Info    restarting tab creation loop
9:27:45 AM  Info    Variable i: 4
9:27:45 AM  Info    Current Session name: undefined
9:27:45 AM  Info    Current Session name: undefined
9:27:45 AM  Info    Setting active range B1 - set value...
9:27:45 AM  Info    Setting values in cells.... Done.
9:27:45 AM  Info    Loop completed for sessions: undefined
9:27:47 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

It seems like you are trying to access sessionNamesArray as a multiple column data rather than multiple row. The structure of the 2d array being fetched by getValues() is variable[row][column]. Looking at your code, you've set the range for sessionNamesArray using multiple rows but 1 column only but inside your loop, you assigned i in the columns part of the 2d array.

### Solution

You can try changing that part of your code to this:

```
  var ActiveSessionName = SessionNamesArray[i][0];
  Logger.log("Current Session name: " + SessionNamesArray[i][0]);
```